# SQL query output months names instead of months numbers

Tags: sql-server

Ho w can I output months **names** instead of months numbers in this query?

```
SELECT        
     YEAR(Periodo) AS year, 
     MONTH(Periodo) AS month, 
     SUM(Paid) AS paid
FROM            
     affitto_sa 
GROUP BY 
    YEAR(Periodo), 
    MONTH(Periodo)
```

Comment: use `Datename(month,Periodo)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT        
     YEAR(Periodo) AS year, 
     Datename(month, Periodo) AS month, 
     SUM(Paid) AS paid
FROM            
     affitto_sa 
GROUP BY 
    YEAR(Periodo), 
    MONTH(Periodo)
```